# How do I make this wordpress theme full width?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I tried my best but I couldn't make the following theme full width/screen by editing the CSS. I'd be very much grateful if you could show me or give me a hint regarding this customization.

http://envirra.com/themes/blackmag/?cat=4

the theme itself has an option for full with and posts without sidebar, but it only displays the header and slider with full width, all the rest, the blog and footer is still boxed

Answer (score 0):

- To create a new page layout you need to access your theme files and
  open up and edit page.php.
- create a template with full-width.php.
- Select a page template in admin page section.

For more information refer following link:

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/create-full-width-page/

Answer (score 0):

Add this css.

```
    @media (min-width: 1200px){
        .category  .container {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have added that code but it doesnt have any effect on the layout